# searching a dictionary to find key value

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using python 2.7 and I have the following dictionary

```
my_dict = {}

my_dict["GI2/1/1"] = [
'switchport port-security maximum 10', 
'switchport port-security maximum 3 vlan access', 
'switchport port-security maximum 1 vlan voice', 
'switchport port-security aging time 25', 
'switchport port-security aging type inactivity', 
'switchport port-security'
]

my_dict["GI2/1/2"] = [
'switchport port-security maximum 5', 
'switchport port-security maximum 5 vlan access', 
'switchport port-security maximum 3 vlan voice', 
'switchport port-security aging time 20', 
'switchport port-security aging type inactivity', 
'switchport port-security'
]


my_dict["GI2/1/3"] = [
'switchport port-security maximum 10', 
'switchport port-security maximum 3 vlan access', 
'switchport port-security maximum 1 vlan voice', 
'switchport port-security aging time 25', 
'switchport port-security aging type inactivity', 
'switchport port-security'
]
```

And I want to be able to search through the values for lets say something like this `switchport port-security maximum 10` and for it to be able to give me all the keys that have that and then be able to get the full value list for that key.

I have the following code but doesn't produce anything

```
x = "port-security maximum 10"

for name, val in my_dict.iteritems():
    if x in val:
        print name
```

Comment: In your example `x = "port-security maximum 10"` but none of the values are actually equal to what x has

Comment: You need to add the word `switchport` to the beginning of `x`, but the point I make in my answer still holds.

Answer (score 2):

**Preface: This answer assumes that your intent is to search for a perfect match to your search string. That implies that `x = 'port-security maximum 10'` was a typo in the original question. If you want to search for a partial string, you will have to do a linear search like the other answers suggest (unless you build a trie up front, but I don't want to go into that).**

Your immediate problem is that `x` does not start with the word `switchport` like all the strings in your values do, so of course it's not found. Your loop is actually totally fine.

If this is an operation you need to do often, reverse the dictionary. The whole point of a dictionary is to allow fast key lookup. Doing a linear search across multiple values seems *very* bad use of your data structure:

```
reversed = {}
for name, val in my_dict.iteritems():
    for key in val:
        if key not in reversed:
            reversed[key] = set()
        reversed[key].add(name)
```

Now you can just do:

```
reversed["switchport port-security maximum 10"]
```

to get

```
set(['GI2/1/1', 'GI2/1/3'])
```

I used a set instead of a list to allow a value in `my_dict` to contain repeats. If that never happens, you may be better off using lists (`.append` instead of `.add`).

Comment: Thanks for this, never though of doing it like this, going to try that out now

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that if statement is supposed to search for `x` in a string but since `val` is a list, it's really checking for it in a list. Add another loop over `val` to get the behavior you want like so:

```
x = "port-security maximum 10"

for name, val in my_dict.iteritems():
    for v in val:
        if x in v:
            print name
```

Comment: Of course it does. But judging by his intended behavior as well as the fact that in his example `x` is not in the list, but is a sub-string of an element in the list, it's safe to assume the check was meant to be done against each element in the list rather than the list itself.

Comment: This actually worked for the search but the only thing is if i were to search for lets say "port-security maximum" it will print out the name 3 times, is there to only print the name once even though its in the list 3 times?

Comment: Yes, you could add a `break` after the `print name`

Comment: You make a solid point. Rather than a typo, OP had something else in mind. Valid solution to valid interpretation. Flipped vote.

Answer (score 1):

I am just writing a for loop for this.

```
for name, val in my_dict.items():
    v = map(lambda l: l.find(x) >= 0, val)
    if any(v):
        print (name)
```

since what you are trying to search for is not exact match, you need to get the index returned by `find`. the final `any` returns true if any of the value is true.

Comment: `l.find(x) >= 0` seems awkward compared to `x in l`.

Comment: Also, the map generator will be exhausted by the list call in py 3 (any will always return false), while the list call is unnecessary in py 2.

Comment: I'm mentioning py 3 because of your print syntax.

Comment: I had a py3 handy. If you look at the 'search string' it's not exact match. So you cannot simply do `x in list`. That's the reason your solution won't work as it is @MadPhysicist. I get your point!! Sorry.. fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
for name, val in my_dict.iteritems():
    combined = '\t'.join(val)
    if x in combined:
        print name
```

Comment: This will not did the problem. OP's issue is due to a typo. This just makes the search more inefficient and provides to explanation.

Comment: @MadPhysicist if he wanted to search "port-security maximum 10" in dictionary won't this solution work?

Comment: Yes. I hadn't considered that x wasn't a typo, given that the description in the prose was inconsistent. Downvote removed.

Comment: @MadPhysicist till now the person havn't said that its a typo. or not even edited his question so i don't think if it's really a typo

Comment: There's a strong implication of it, since the prose states "And I want to be able to search through the values for lets say something like this `switchport port-security maximum 10`"

Comment: Also, OP's comment to my answer implies the same. I agree that it was never admitted by OP to be a typo.